# Get version of installed Flash ActiveX in Win32/C++

Tags: c++, winapi, activex

Is this even possible?

I'm embedding Flash inside an IE frame in my application and would like to check if Flash and what version of it is installed.

The application needs to run without admin privileges.

Bonus question: Can I also check if ActiveX controls are enabled in the IE settings?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751968(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to search for the CLSID of Flash (`"{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}"`) in the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`.

There you can read `\InprocServer32` which gives you the OCX. Then get the version via `GetFileVersionInfo`.

This should work for any COM control.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind is to examine the file version of the corresponding *.dll or *.ocx file. On my 64-bit system, the file is

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\Flash10b.ocx
```

As you probably are aware of, many applications can list all installed ActiveX controls. So it is definitely possible to obtain the file name programmatically. And once you have, you can just get the file version.

Hopefully someone else can give you a slightly more enlightened answer soon.

**Update**

Now that I think about it, there is one key per control in the registry.